# On neutral Kaon mixing

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, mesons, pions, cp-violation

Kaons are not eigenstates of $CP$:
$$
CP|K\rangle =|\overline K\rangle\\
$$
Why do we need to mix them?

[image]

One answer I read is "since they both decay into $2$ or $3$ pions". Couldn't they just decay in the same thing and that's it? There are many other particles that happen to decay the same way, but we don't mix them.

**Addendum*. Citing from "Mixing and Oscillations of Particles" by Andrzej K. Wroblewski:

> In 1955 Murray Gell-Mann and Abraham Pais analyzed the behavior of neutral particles under the operation $C$ of charge conjugation which changes every particle into its anti-particle. According to the proposed scheme of classification of $K$ mesons, the neutral kaon $K^0$ was assumed to possess an anti-particle $\overline{K}^0$
> distinct from itself.
> **Gell-Mann and Pais were able to show that in that case the neutral kaon must be considered to be a “particle mixture”, exhibiting two distinct lifetimes and different decay modes.**

What were the reasons that brought Gell-Mann and Pais to this conclusion?

Comment: Why did you include those diagrams? You don't comment on them but it seems to me that they answer your question.

Comment: Strangeness oscillations is an experimental phenomenon. It was observed, so it was inferred that flavor mixing occurred; copiously for this system, but much more weakly for other systems. What is your point, really? *What* are you asking? Your read what where?

Comment: I'm asking if $K$ oscillations were known *before* considering the possibility that they could violate $CP$ parity OR if these oscillations were introduced to justify the $CP$ violation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a terrible misconception to predicate flavor mixing (strangeness oscillations here) on CP violation. Flavor mixing was investigated (Gell-Mann―Pais, 1955, and the experiments probing it, [1957](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.106.591), 1960) for a decade (1955-1964) before the discovery of CP violation in 1964 (Fitch―Cronin).

CP violation is just a minuscule twist on the flavor oscillation of neutral mesons like the weak diagrams you are displaying, and is not a precondition for it: just a minute phenomenon riding on phases attached to ***small*** CKM matrix elements in your box diagrams.

*Edit to address the altered question decoupling from CP violation*. The point of the Gell-Mann―Pais [paper](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.97.1387), was that the  masses of the odd and even CP eigenstates, KL, KS, were slightly different, with vastly different lifetimes, exactly what you'd get from a strong Hamiltonian with small doubly weak off-diagonal mixing terms, upon diagonalization of the mass matrix.